# Como diminuir a sensibilidade do Iscroll5?

Tags: iscroll5

Eu estou a usar o plguin Iscroll para percorrer mostrar uma lista num aparelho IOS.

Estive à procura no site de onde saquei o plugin ([aqui](http://iscrolljs.com/)), mas não encontrei nenhuma informação sobre o diminuir/aumentar a sensibilidade do scroll.

Existe alguma instrução que o faça?

**UPDATE**

```
Inicialização do IScroll

        var wrapper = document.getElementById('treelist');
        myScroll = new IScroll(wrapper, {
            scrollX : false,
            scrollY : true,
            scrollbars : false,
            interactiveScrollbars : true,
            mouseWheel : true,
            hScrollbar : false,
            vScrollbar : true,
            useTransition : false,
            snap : 'li',
            tap: true,
            click: true,
            mouseWheelSpeed: 1,

            indicators : {
                el : '#scroller',
                fade : false,
                ignoreBoundaries : false,
                interactive : false,
                listenX : false,
                listenY : true,
                resize : false,
                shrink : false,
                speedRatioX : 0,
                speedRatioY : 0,
                checkDOMChanges: true,
            },

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Nesse mesmo site existe a parte de *comandos avançados* que pode ser vista aqui: http://iscrolljs.com/#advanced-options

Acredito que o que você procura é:

```
options.mouseWheelSpeed
Modifica a velocidade do scroll do mouse.
Valor padrão: 20
```

Se quiser alterar a aceleração/tempo de parada do movimento é com o `options.deceleration`.

Comment: vou experimentar, mas não creio, pois eu não estou a usar a roda do rato

Comment: Continua sendo scroll, independente do mouse/rato/camundongo/dedo :D

Comment: acho que não funcionou, pelo menos já experimentei por `mouseWheelSpeed: 1` e `mouseWheelSpeed: 100` para ver a diferença, e não notei nada. Pode ser que tenha poucos elementos para percorrer para notar a diferença?

Comment: Como está a fazer a declaração desses comandos?

Comment: Fiz um upadte na pergunta, adicionei lá o codigo javascript que inicializa o iscroll